# Retrieve column based on closest date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Thanks for your help in advance. I have an `invoice` table which is similar to below:

```
INV DATE    | ITEM  |SELL PRICE |COST PRICE
------------+-------+-----------+----------
30/06/2016  | DOOR1 |10         |5
```

The above item is sourced from the EU so I have another table (`VEN_HIS`) which lists a history of supplier prices for that item as below:

```
DATE        |ITEM   |CURRENCY   |PRICE
------------+-------+-----------+------
17/05/2017  |DOOR1  |EUR        |6
01/01/2017  |DOOR1  |EUR        |5.8
29/05/2016  |DOOR1  |EUR        |5.6
05/03/2016  |DOOR1  |EUR        |5.5
```

What I want to do is join the tables to drop in the correct currency price we would have paid onto the invoice table as at the invoice date in other words the correct price is 5.6

This is my first post and I need to get some FX analysis done quickly so apologies for the formatting, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple question of `Join` and `where` clause.

```
create table #t1 (INV_DATE DATE,ITEM varchar(100), SELL_PRICE int, COST_PRICE int);
insert into #t1 values
('30/06/2016','DOOR1',10,5)

create table #ven_his (colDATE date, ITEM varchar(100), CURRENCY varchar(100),PRICE float);
insert into #ven_his values
('17/05/2017',  'DOOR1',  'EUR',6  ),
('01/01/2017',  'DOOR1',  'EUR',5.8),
('29/05/2016',  'DOOR1',  'EUR',5.6),
('05/03/2016',  'DOOR1',  'EUR',5.5) 


SELECT top 1 a.INV_DATE, a.ITEM, b.CURRENCY, b.PRICE
FROM #t1 a
left join #ven_his b
on a.ITEM = b.ITEM
WHERE b.colDATE <=a.INV_DATE
ORDER BY b.colDATE DESC
```

output :

```
#t1
INV_DATE   ITEM   SELL_PRICE  COST_PRICE
---------- ------ ----------- -----------
2016-06-30 DOOR1  10          5


#ven_his
colDATE    ITEM      CURRENCY     PRICE
---------- --------- ------------ ------
2017-05-17 DOOR1     EUR          6
2017-01-01 DOOR1     EUR          5.8
2016-05-29 DOOR1     EUR          5.6
2016-03-05 DOOR1     EUR          5.5


INV_DATE   ITEM      CURRENCY    PRICE
---------- --------- ----------- --------
2016-06-30 DOOR1     EUR         5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @invoice table (INV_Date date, Item varchar(100),SellPrice numeric(5,2), Costprice numeric(5,2))

INSERT INTO @invoice

SELECT '20160630','DOOR1',10,5

SELECT * FrOm @invoice





DECLARE @ven_his table(Dates date,Item varchar(100),Currency varchar(10),Price numeric(5,2))

INSERT INTO @ven_his

SELECT '20170517','DOOR1','EUR',6

UNION ALL

SELECT '20170101','DOOR1','EUR',5.8

UNION ALL

SELECT '20160529','DOOR1','EUR',5.6

UNION ALL

SELECT '20160305','DOOR1','EUR',5.5



SELECT * FROM @ven_his



SELECT Top 1 i.Item,INV_Date,PRICE,Dates

FROM @invoice i

JOIN @ven_his v

ON i.Item = v.Item

ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,i.INV_Date,v.Dates))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LEAD function to return the correct price for all items:

```
    Create table #Invoice (INVDATE DATE, ITEM NVARCHAR(20), SELLPRICE SMALLMONEY, COSTPRICE SMALLMONEY)

    INSERT #INVOICE VALUES ('2016-06-30', 'DOOR1', 10, 5)
    --Test with additional invoices
    --INSERT #INVOICE VALUES ('2017-02-22', 'DOOR1', 10, 5), ('2016-09-22', 'DOOR1', 10, 5)

    CREATE TABLE #VENHIS ([DATE] DATE, ITEM NVARCHAR(20), CURRENCY NVARCHAR(5), PRICE SMALLMONEY)

    INSERT #VENHIS VALUES ('2017-05-17', 'DOOR1', 'EUR', 6), ('2017-01-01', 'DOOR1', 'EUR', 5.8),('2016-05-29', 'DOOR1', 'EUR', 5.6), ('2016-03-05', 'DOOR1', 'EUR', 5.5)

    SELECT I.*, V.PRICE 
    FROM #Invoice i
    INNER JOIN (SELECT *, [DATE] as STARTDATE, LEAD([DATE])  OVER (PARTITION BY  ITEM ORDER BY ITEM, [DATE] ASC)  AS EndDate
    FROM   #VENHIS ) v ON i.ITEM=v.ITEM AND I.[INVDATE] BETWEEN V.STARTDATE AND DATEADD(D,-1,ISNULL(V.ENDDATE, '2099-01-01'))
```